# Getting the Wanted Array of Strings

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. Below is an array of strings. My problem is how am I going to get the strings that I want from the array of strings? An example is shown below. Any suggestion would be great. Thank you. =)

Given that:

```
varying vec4 color;
uniform float displacement;

void main() {
   vec3 newPos = position + normal  +  normal  +  normal  -  4.075480981464672  *  6.31185739715362  -  9.118399331842484  /  displacement  *  normal  *  normal  *  normal  /  normal  +  displacement  *  4.766234109448448  *  displacement  -  5.5938257407596375  *  normal  ;
   color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPos, 1.0);
}
```

Wanted strings:

```
vec3 newPos = position + normal  +  normal  +  normal  -  4.075480981464672  *  6.31185739715362  -  9.118399331842484  /  displacement  *  normal  *  normal  *  normal  /  normal  +  displacement  *  4.766234109448448  *  displacement  -  5.5938257407596375  *  normal  ;
```

Comment: Is this *real* JavaScript or Unity3D JavaScript?

Comment: It is real Javascript =)

Comment: What are you using this JavaScript for? it doesn't really look like js

Comment: That syntax is weird and wrong then. `varying` ?? `vec3` ?? `uniform` ??

Comment: it is an array of concatenated C code in Strings that is returned from a Javascript function.

Comment: This is not C code but a C similar language called GLSL which is used to program shaders. I noticed that your wanted string is slightly different that the first line of the main function. Now are you looking to isolate that line or modify it?

Comment: @LeJeuneRenard I would like to modify that wanted string. But I do not have a clue how to extract that wanted line of strings and modify it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your reasoning for extracting the 'wanted string' is that you want to extract the first line declaring the `vec3 newPos` from the shader, you can use javascript's `.match()` to extract the line like so:

```
var wantedString = shader.match(/(vec3 newPos.*)/)[0]
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n88kdyoc/) of it in action.